# Does browserify API need vinyl object?

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, browserify

I'm trying to browserify some angular files and integrate them into my gulp tasks. While trying to get the gulp plugin for browserify I came across this https://github.com/gulpjs/plugins/issues/47

> Browserify should be used as a standalone module. It returns a stream and figures out your dependency graph. If you need vinyl objects, use browserify + vinyl-source-stream

I'm ashamed to say that I didn't know what vinyl objects were and after reading up a bit I came across this.

> Vinyl is a very simple metadata object that describes a file.

And apparently you need vinyl adapters to expose `.src, .watch and .dest`? So, I'm guessing `vinyl-source-stream` is that sort of adapter? I guess what I don't understand is why would I need vinyl object in my browserify when I can simply do this:-

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    browserify = require('browserify');

gulp.task('browserify', function(){
    browserify('./js/index.js')
    .bundle()
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./js/bundle.js'));
```

And instead have to do this:-

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    source = require('vinyl-source-stream'),
    browserify = require('browserify');

gulp.task('browserify', function(){
    browserify('./js/index.js')
    .bundle()
    .pipe(source('./js/index.js')) //this line in particular
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./js/bundle.js'));
```

Apologize if this doesn't make sense. I'll edit this if it needs more explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just pipe to the string `'./js/bundle.js'`. You use `source` to attach a name to the new file created by `bundle`, then you pipe the stream of file(s) to it's destination directory:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    source = require('vinyl-source-stream'),
    browserify = require('browserify');

gulp.task('browserify', function(){
   return browserify('./js/index.js')
    .bundle()
    .pipe(source('bundle.js')) //this line in particular
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./js'));
```

Comment: Oops, my bad on that part. Edited the original.
However, my question was why do I have to use `.bundle().pipe(source('bundle/js')).pipe(gulp.dest('bundle.js'))` instead of just piping it to destination. `.bundle().pipe(gulp.dest('bundle.js'))`;

Comment: `gulp.dest` pipes a stream of files into a directory, it doesn't handle renaming a single file.

Comment: Ahh. I see. It makes so much sense now. Thanks for the clarification.